# Form.Show() giving error

Tags: vb.net

When ever I try having the user push a button to make another form come up I get an error.

```
Private Sub client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    statuslabel.Text = "Installation Complete!"
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    My.Settings.doneSender = "vanilla"
    My.Settings.Save()
    Me.Hide()
    done.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

It shows an error at done.show(), done is its own form.
Error: Name can be simplified. Reference to non-shared member requires an object reference. When I press fix it just changed it to Show(). It was working before with done.show() IDK what happened.

Comment: where is `done` declared?

Comment: `done` is object or class? Looks like it has two methods. One is static and another is instance member.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is a class

Comment: it was working just fine earlier this error just appeared out of nowhere I didn't change any code I just tried to run it and this error started

Comment: It's impossible for us to determine what the problem is without more information. You'll need to include the code for your entire class, to provide the necessary context.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your faulty line of code with:

```
Dim frmDone as New done
frmDone.show()
```

Comment: Note: I haven't typed a line of vb.net for a couple of years now, hopefully I got the syntax correct.